# Expedia: how to interpret / use the prices on the calendar while searching for flights?

Tags: expedia

How do I interpret / use these prices on the calendar?
They look different from the price in the search results.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prices are usually cached and is updated periodically only for widgets like calendar. The lower priced buckets of tickets might have been just sold off and it will take a while to update the calendar. The price showing at checkout will be usually correct.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, unfortunately I am finding the actual prices are more than double what is shown on the calendar widget. This makes that feature pretty much worthless to check dates in the same range.

Comment: On some sites you may found the price for each leg or the price for the return trip shown depending on where you look not sure what Expedia does.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/152134)